# How would one integrate Google Docs into your web application for Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a web application that currently stores documents for users on my site in my Amazon S3 bucket. I am looking to enable users to open and edit their documents from my S3 bucket using Google Docs. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to open your documents hosted on S3 from Google Docs, unless you get your users to save them first.

I have a crazy idea that could work:

1. Share the documents with your users (either by making them public or just sharing the link).
2. Use Google Drive to sync those documents with some server.
3. Periodically upload the documents to s3.